# SELECT TOP N with UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the example below, why does using using `UNION ALL` with two `SELECT TOP 5` statements in Query 2 below seemingly not respect the `ORDER BY` clause?

Query 1 returns the expected results but does not include the required union.
Query 2 demonstrates the unexpected behavior.
Query 3 is the workaround I'm currently using to get the desired results.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 ([ID] int IDENTITY(1,1), [Description] varchar(100), [Inactive] bit);
CREATE TABLE #T2 ([ID] int IDENTITY(1,1), [Description] varchar(100), [Inactive] bit);

INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('One', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Two', 0);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Three', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Four', 0);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Five', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Six', 0);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Seven', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Eight', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Nine', 1);
INSERT INTO #T1([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Ten', 0);

-- Query 1, works as expected giving all 4 records with Inactive = 0 plus one more
SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
FROM #T1
ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]; 

-- Query 2, does not work as expected, as only 2 of the Inactive = 0 records are present
SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
FROM #T1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
FROM #T2
ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]; 

-- Query 3, Workaround to produce desired results
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
    FROM #T1
    ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]
),
T2 AS (
    SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
    FROM #T2
    ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]
)
SELECT [ID], [Description], [Inactive] FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT [ID], [Description], [Inactive] FROM T2
ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]; 

DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
```

Obviously, the workaround is working for me but I'd like to understand why Query 2 does not do what I expected it to.  In case you're wondering why I am bothering with the empty table `#T2`, the results are actually limited by a `WHERE` clause in my production example - however leaving it empty here serves the purpose of providing a comparable example without bothering to populate it.

If you do populate `#T2` with the following, I find the results to be just as strange - Query 2 only gives four results with `Inactive = 0`.

```
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Eleven', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Twelve', 0);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Thirteen', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Fourteen', 0);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Fifteen', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Sixteen', 0);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Seventeen', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Eighteen', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Nineteen', 1);
INSERT INTO #T2([Description], [Inactive]) VALUES ('Twenty', 0);
```

I have run this script with the same results on SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A Union query works thus: execute the queries, then apply the order by clause. So with

```
SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
FROM #T1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
FROM #T2
ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description];
```

you select five arbitrarily chosen records from #T1 plus five arbitrarily chosen records from #T2 and then you order these. So you need subqueries or with clauses. E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (
    SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
    FROM #T1
    ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive]
    FROM #T2
    ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]
  )
) t;
```

So your workaround is not a workaround at all, but the proper query.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down that way, I'll probably accept your answer if I don't hear anything earth shattering soon.  I guess it just surprises me that since `ORDER BY` usually applies to all parts of a union that it responds that way when combining it with `TOP N`

Comment: Well, it always applies to the *result* of the union (which is too late for the top clauses to make sense).

Answer (score 6):

You should move the whole UNION ALL within a subquery:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM (SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive] 
>       FROM #T1 
>       ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT TOP 5 [ID], [Description], [Inactive] 
>       FROM #T2 
>       ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description]) T3
> ORDER BY [Inactive], [Description];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Description | Inactive
> -: | :---------- | :-------
>  4 | Four        | False   
>  6 | Six         | False   
> 10 | Ten         | False   
>  2 | Two         | False   
>  8 | Eight       | True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference between query #2 and #3 - the ORDER BY clause on #T1.

The thumb rule is -in a SQL query if you don't specify the ORDER BY cause, "TOP" will just return random set of records. After you get these "random" rows, the sorting comes into play. And hence there is no "proper" sorting taking place.

Comment: Agreed, but typically doesn't `ORDER BY` apply to both parts of a union?  You can't specify an order by for an individual section of a union, just at the end of the entire query.